# Custom text to <a> tag using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a two `<a>` tags and it's `HTML` as below:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">This is my link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">This is my link</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want is, to replace links text as this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">custom 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">custom 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is how I tried it using `CSS`. But still I couldn't figure this out.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a:first-child:after {
  content: 'Custom 1';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul li a:last-child:after {
  content: 'Custom 2';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Hope somebody may help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul li:first-child a:before {
  content: 'Custom 1';
  position: absolute;
  color: DodgerBlue;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul li:last-child a:before {
  content: 'Custom 2';
  position: absolute;
  color: DodgerBlue;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">This is my link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">This is my link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can we hide actual text without using `a{color: #fff}` ? In my case background color is dynamic.

Comment: Yes. try to add white background color to pseudo element, so it will hide text behind

Comment: Yes I tried it. but its showing white background as a button

Comment: Edited answer. You need to some CSS changes.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make it dynamicly, you should use a Script.. 
With this snnipet : 
document.getElementById("ahref1").innerHTML = "Google";

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I am looking for a `CSS` solution